# Delete name from database

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp web page. I need to delete the username from database when i press the delete button from the web page. I tried the codes below but I cant delete the name, instead it insert a new row and an empty value in the username database.

Here's my codes

UnblockServlet.java :

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

String username = request.getParameter("username");

```
System.out.println("username="+username);


CustomerInfor unblockUser = new CustomerInfor();


unblockUser.setUsername(username);




CustomerInforDBAO unblockuserdb = new CustomerInforDBAO();


String status = unblockuserdb.blockUser(unblockUser);
System.out.println("Deleted user from blocked:" + status);

if (status== "success"){
    dispatch(request,response,"/success.jsp");  

}

else{
    dispatch(request,response,"/error.jsp");
```

}

}

CustomerInforDBAO.java :

```
public String unblockUser(CustomerInfor unblockUser){
    Connection con = getConnection(true);
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    int status=1;
    String select = "DELETE * FROM paybuddy.blocked where username=?";
    try{
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(select);
        stmt.setInt(1,unblockUser.getId());
        stmt.setString(2,unblockUser.getUsername());

        status = stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        unblockUser = null;
    } finally {
        try{
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
            if (con != null) con.close();
        }catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
    if(status!=1)
        return "error";
    else
        return "success";

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String unblockUser(CustomerInfor unblockUser){
Connection con = getConnection(true);
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
int status=1;
String select = "DELETE  FROM paybuddy.blocked where username=?"; // no *
try{
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(select);
    //stmt.setInt(1,unblockUser.getId()); is this needed?
    stmt.setString(1,unblockUser.getUsername());

    status = stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    unblockUser = null;
} finally {
    try{
        if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        if (con != null) con.close();
    }catch (SQLException e) {}
}
if(status!=1)
    return "error";
else
    return "success";

    }
```

and check if ur calling the proper function above.

```
String status = unblockuserdb.blockUser(unblockUser);
```

should it be

```
String status = unblockuserdb.unblockUser(unblockUser);
```

Comment: HEY! thanx for the help. I can delete the name at the databse.

Comment: are u getting any exceptions? and is the function returning success?